# Get jQuery value from unvalidating input field

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have an input field of type number. It requires a number like 21.5 or 0.1 but it fails an 21,5 or 0,1
I don't care actually abouth the seperator since I'm handling it in php, but I can't sent it using Ajax since it's not valide.
But I like to keep the type="number" to force mobiledevices to show the num-pad.
So I thought it should be pretty easy just to replace the comma by dot before sending it. But therfore I need to get the value of the inputfield.

Is there a method to get the value even it's not validating?

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" min=0 step=0.1 id="numberinput" title="test"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0rdhnew/

`document.getElementById('numberinput').value` and `$('#numberinput').val()` are not working, see example in the fiddle.

Comment: This is a good question. I don't see any reason to down vote it. I can only assume that whoever did it don't quite understand the question.

Comment: Simply reproduced in this: `a=document.createElement('input');a.type='number';a.setAttribute('value', 'a');a.value; // ""`

Comment: I tested it on Chromium and Firefox, latest versions

Answer (score 1):

First, put your event handlers in a document.ready block.  Next, use keypress instead of change for the event on a textbox.  Lastly, it looks like the pattern is preventing the correct value from being retrieved.  One solution that will surely work is to write your own event handler to validate the keystrokes:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var regExPattern = "[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?"; //You will have to troubleshoot this
    $("#numberinput").keypress(function(e){
        if (!regExPattern.test($("#numberinput").val() + e.val()){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            }
        else
            $("#out").text($("#numberinput").val() + e.val());
    });
});
```

This code is untested, but should work.  Hopefully someone else will have a better way, but I think that pattern thing is your problem, here.  I've never seen a control prevent you from retrieving its value, before.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample MaskDecimal function:

```
function MaskDecimal(e) {
  var CurrentValue = $(this).val();
  var dotkey = [190, 46];   // try to catch inconsistent key mapping
  var commakey = [188, 44]; // see: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html
  if (dotkey.indexOf(e.which ) > -1 || commakey.indexOf(e.which ) > -1) {
    if (CurrentValue.indexOf(".") > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else if (CurrentValue == "") {
        $(this).val("0.");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else if( commakey.indexOf(e.which ) > -1 ){
        $(this).val(CurrentValue +'.');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
  }                       
  // allow only digits, backspace and enter:
  else if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && !(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0rdhnew/4/

You would assign this MaskDecimal to your textboxes like so:

```
$("#numberinput").on("keypress", MaskDecimal);
```

Don't forget to reference your JS file on your page if that's where you put your MaskDecimal function!

Comment: I tested it before without pattern, but the pattern actually should just allow the comma. It works if I replace the type number by type text. But then the normal keyboard on mobile devices is used instead of numpad.

Comment: Understood - but just calling something 'number' but allowing alphabetic keystrokes is a bit flawed.  You could easily write a 'MaskDecimal' function and stick it in a javascript file - and then just assign that function to each 'Decimal' textbox in your solution, like so:  (inside document ready, of course) $("#textBoxID").on("keypress", MasDecimal);

Comment: I edited my answer with some more info for you.  I hope this helps.

Comment: And to clarify, you can keep your type="number" - just get rid of that pattern - instead you should be masking the textbox to prevent invalid characters from being accepted in the first place!

Comment: I slightly modified your function to accept comma and converting it on the fly to dot. I upvoted, because this is a acceptable workaround. But I will wait a little time for accepting, because this is actually not the solution to the problem.

Comment: I agree, but I think this is preferable to a direct solution to the question, because if you were able to get the value, even if the pattern didn't match, you would still be accepting invalid characters from the user.  In my opinion, it is far better to disallow invalid characters than to allow them and display error messages.  However, I am interested to see if someone else has the 'true' answer, because like I said, I've never seen .val() fail before.  Great question!

Comment: argh... tested it out. Running into issues with Firefox and Firefox Mobile on Android. 1st Firefox is not keeping the currentVal after comma input. It deletes it all. 2nd keypress-, keydown, input- events seems not to be recognized at all using firefox mobile touch numpad...

Comment: solved one problem with not recognizing dot and comma in firefox at all: added correct firefox keycodes for dot and comma, see: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `keydown` event and prevent the value from being set when non numeric characters is typed, as well as replacing comma with dot:

```
myInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // not 0-9
    if ( event.which < 48 || event.which > 57 ) {
        // comma:
        if ( event.which == 188 ) {
            this.value += '.';
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The above code doesn't support the numpad and the decimal key as well as comma in the middle of the value:

> 123|456 -> (cursor is |) user pressed , ->  123456.